# How to make 'mouse wheel' event listener function less responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an effect were the image and color of a page change when the wheel on a mouse is moved. I have achieved this, but the problem  I am facing now is that the effect is almost instantaneous, just the slightest of movements of the wheel and the event is triggered.

How can I make the mouse wheel event less responsive (gradual) as [here](http://brightmedia.pl/?lang=en&site=intro) (the effect is a bit popular, sorry I could find any better examples). Thanks in advance for the help. Sorry in advance for poor explanation or trivial question.

```
function mouseHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.deltaY);

    // This is where my problem is, I cannot think of another way besides this.
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        position = position === 0 ? pages.length - 1 : position - 1;
    } else {
        position = (position + 1) % pages.length;
    }

    $(".banner_image").fadeOut(0);

    if (pages[position] === "../../public/images/Avatar.png") {

        $("body").css("background-color", "#00a8ff");

        $(".navigation-wrapper").css("background-color", "#00a8ff");

        $(".banner").css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: "50%",
            left: "25%",
            transform: "(-50%, -50%)"
        });

    }
    else if (pages[position] === "../../public/images/Burger.png") {
        $("body").css("background-color", "#e84118");

        $(".navigation-wrapper").css("background-color", "#e84118");

        $(".banner").css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: "50%",
            left: "25%",
            transform: "(-50%, -50%)"
        });
    }
    else if (pages[position] === "../../public/images/IceCream2.png") {
        $("body").css("background-color", "#f1c40f");

        $(".navigation-wrapper").css("background-color", "#f1c40f");

        $(".banner").css({
            position: "fixed",
            top: "50%",
            left: "25%",
            transform: "(-50%, -50%)"
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for either a **debounce** or **throttle** method.

*Debounce* will make sure that your code runs only once at the end of a set of invocations, even if the function is called many times.

*Throttle* will make sure a function runs a max of X times per second irrespective of how times it's called.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

http://underscorejs.org/#throttle